# resize2fs: Not enough reserved gdt blocks for resizing

Tags: arm, 32bit, resize2fs

I'm trying to resize rootfs partion from 250Gb to 1000Gb.

```
# sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem at /dev/sda1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 15, new_desc_blocks = 59
resize2fs: Not enough reserved gdt blocks for resizing
```

Disks:

```
# sudo fdisk -l

...

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa7eaa73d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1953523215   976760584   83  Linux
```

File system:

```
# sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          276eeebb-6d0e-4ac9-98ac-ed5835989624
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              15299712
Block count:              61049600
Reserved block count:     2520034
Free blocks:              55776421
Free inodes:              14996879
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      41
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8208
Inode blocks per group:   513
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Sep 23 09:48:57 2014
Last mount time:          Sun Apr  3 18:36:38 2016
Last write time:          Sun Apr  3 18:36:38 2016
Mount count:              43
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Sep 23 09:48:57 2014
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          17 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      f78f18f6-5aaf-4207-aa21-8ec89212504c
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Free space:

```
# sudo df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       230G   17G  204G   8% /
...
```

It is on 32-bit ARM device, did I hit some limit? Is it possibly to overcome it?

Answer (score 2):

According to a [discussion on Linux kernel](http://markmail.org/message/k5m5qkjz3rrxeakx) mailing list, it is a bug in `resize2fs` (apparently no workaround):

> OK, based on your description, you started with a device which was 8001057980416 bytes, and then grew it to 22002909446144 bytes. So I tried to exactly the same thing using a file located on an xfs partition (so I could make it that big):

and

> Given that I was primarily focused on making resize2fs work using on-line resizing, this doesn't completely surprise me, but it is definitely a bug with resize2fs that needs fixing --- we need to make off-line resizing work, and if there are bugs related to it, we need to simply make resize2fs refuse to do the off-line resize.